# Power Query - Create a custom column that returns the latest value of another row by matching two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

In power query, I want to create a custom column that returns the date only if:

- Column B equals "Endorsement" or "Cancellation"
- takes the account number of that row, matches it by the previous but most recent record row of the same account number where column b is equal to "New" or "Renewal" AND only if column R is not negative or does not contain certain text "abc" in column S (the same account has multiple rows based on transaction)
- returns the date of that row in the custom column

I have trouble thinking of a logical solution for this problem

Comment: Please post some sample data as text.

Comment: https://easyupload.io/e2nd8q

Comment: It is probably doable, but your description is not clear. In particular, your columns letters do not contain your desired data as shown in the link of sample data you provided; and also an example of your desired results would be useful in trying to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds quite complex but certainly possible within PQ.

My approach to this requirement would be to build a query for merging, that returns the set of rows meeting your criteria: *column b is equal to "New"* ...

A key component would be a nested running count (within groups of account number) on the main query.  On the query for merging, I would subtract 1 from that running count, to achieve the requirement *matches it by the previous but most recent record*.

There are a few solutions around to achieve a running total or count in PQ, this is my current favourite:
https://exceloffthegrid.com/power-query-running-total/

The final steps would be in the main query to add a Merge step (to the new query for merging, on account number + running count), then an Expand step to return the date from the query for merging.

Comment: I'm trying to search up if PQ has a similar WHERE clause like SQL. I actually don't need the condition where it checks for certain text. I only need the condition that column R is not negative, thus the query will check the next row in the list. So in essence, create a custom column with the following conditions: checks if column b equals "Endorsement" or "Cancellation", matches previous row where column b is "new" or "renewal, returns date of row only if column R of that row > 0

Comment: my current data is sorted by recorded date of the account. So "news" and "renewals" will appear before "transactions" and "cancellations" of the same account number

Comment: WHERE in SQL => Filter button in PQ. It generates a Table.SelectRows function call.

Comment: I have one more question. When PQ generates the table after clicking "Close & Load", does it automatically show the formulas for special columns as well? For example if custom Column C is doing column (a*b)+10, then will every row in column C, if I double click that column, show as (A1*B1)+10, (A2*B2)+10, etc....

Comment: The columns loaded by PQ will only show the values, never as formulas. You can add columns later in traditional Excel, but it's a bit flaky on refresh.

Comment: when i created my PQ query, i loaded the source from my workbook, and loaded it as a table. Applied my PQ steps and thats it. So whenever I open my report PQ wbook, i only have a copy of the generated PQ report table, I don't have another tab for the source worksheet of the source workbook. Let's say my manager reviews my end month report after I have refreshed my workbook, and she notices an account is missing on the generated report table. When I insert a new row to insert that account and try to refresh, my worksheet will delete that row since it is not part of the source workbook.

Comment: Is there any way to remedy this solution? Will I have to start over again and make sure when I load the source worksheet from the accounts workbook, I have to load as a connection? My thinking is that after you open the report workbook, refresh it to get the new entries at the end of the month, you will have to unlink the query on the table. If something needs to be added or modified, then refreshing wont override the changes in the table.

Comment: You will probably need to change the query, but shouldn't need to start over.  The query steps are editable.

Comment: sorry, which part of my query would I need to change? Is there a way for excel to refresh for the 2nd time your table without overriding changes you have made for special accounts after the initial refresh? Something to do with having two of the same tables/queries open?